# Is there any built-in function to extract elements from list in Scheme?

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, racket

Is there any function to transform

'((0 0 0) (4 0 0) (2 7 0)) into '(0 0 0 4 0 0 2 7 0)

Answer (score 1):

Standard Scheme (RnRS for some definition of n) does not provide such a function, but what you want to do is commonly called `flatten` and is available in many Scheme libraries. On the chance that this is homework I won't provide code, but here is a skeleton that will get you started:

```
(define (flatten xs)
  (cond ((null? xs) ...)
        ((pair? xs)
          (append (flatten ...)
                  (flatten ...)))
        (else ...)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you're looking for is called [`flatten`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._flatten%29%29), which will flatten all sublists no matter their level of nesting:

```
(flatten '((0 0 0) (4 0 0) (2 7 0)))
```

In case your interpreter doesn't support it, the usual way to implement it (for one level of nesting) is:

```
(apply append '((0 0 0) (4 0 0) (2 7 0)))
```

Or like this, for arbitrarily nested lists (this is how the built-in `flatten` works):

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((pair? lst)
         (append (flatten (car lst)) (flatten (cdr lst))))
        (else (list lst))))
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
'(0 0 0 4 0 0 2 7 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right, I had to implement it. This one works for the example

```
(define (extract lista)
   (if (equal? lista empty) '() (append (car lista) (extract(cdrlista)))))
```